# Show $ \int _0^t \frac{\left|B_u \right|}{u}du < \infty \ a.e.$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How to show that for all $t\geq 0$ $$ \int _0^t \frac{\left|B_u \right|}{u}du < \infty \ a.e.,$$
where $ \left( B_t \right)_{t\geq 0}$ is the real standard brownian motion starting from zero ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Fubini-Tonelli theorem and Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, we have
$$
E\left[\int_0^t \frac{|B_u|}{u}\,du\right] = \int_0^t\frac{E(|B_u|)}{u}\,du \leq \int_0^t \frac{E(B_u^2)^{1/2}}{u}\,du = \int_0^t \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} =2\sqrt{t} <\infty.
$$

**Edit:** As noted by did, the expectation can be computed exactly:

$$
E\left[\int_0^t \frac{|B_u|}{u}\,du\right] = \sqrt{\frac{8t}{\pi}}.
$$

Comment: By scaling, $E(|B_u|)=\sqrt{u}E(|B_1|)$ hence Cauchy-Schwarz is not required.

Comment: You're right of course, but it gives the bound $E(|B_1|) \leq 1$.

Comment: Which is perfect, no?

Comment: @StefanHansen: It's not perfect since $E(|B_1|) = \sqrt{2/\pi} < 1$.

Comment: Which changes nothing to show the wanted result. Enven if it's refined estimation. Thank you, everybody!

Comment: @Ju'x: I meant perfect in the sense that the upper bound is unimportant as long as it's finite.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that 
$$
E\left[\int_0^t \frac{|B_u|}{u}\,\mathrm du\right]<\infty
$$
by the use of Tonelli's theorem.