# Continuous local martingales with same crochet have the same law?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider $M= \left(M\right )_{t \geq0}, \ N=\left(N\right) _{t \geq0} \in \mathcal M_{c,loc} $ starting both from zero, such that, a.e.$ \langle M \rangle_t =\langle N \rangle_t, \ \forall t\geq 0$.

Have $M$ and $N$ the same law? If not give a contre exemple.

Answer (score 7):

No. $M$ and $N$ need not have the same distribution. For example, take
$$
Z_t = \exp\left\{B_t - \frac{t}{2}\right\},\qquad M_t = Z_t - 1,\qquad N_t = 1 -Z_t.
$$

The continuous martingales $M$ and $N$ have the same quadratic variation $\langle Z\rangle_t$, but since $Z_t$ tends to $0$ as $t \to +\infty$ a.s. they cannot have the same distribution.

**Proof that $Z_t \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} 0$ a.s.**

We know that $\dfrac{B_t}{t} \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} 0$ as a consequence of the strong law of large numbers (or the law of the iterated logarithm). From this we deduce that
$$Z_t = \exp\left\{t \left(\frac{B_t}{t}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \right\}\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} 0\quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: How to show that $Z_t \longrightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow + \infty$ ?

Comment: How to show that $t Y_t \rightarrow \infty $ where $Y_t =\frac{B_t}{t} \rightarrow \infty$? I'm not confortable with the limt of the product of t tending to infinit with something wich tends to zero. I'm not convinced

Comment: Hmm. You might want to read again what I wrote.

Comment: @Ju'x : Sorry I make  a mistake when writing. I'd like to say: How to assurate that $tY_t \rightarrow 0 $ a.s. if $Y_t \rightarrow 0 $ a.s, particularly when  $Y_t =\frac{B_t}{t} $ ?